# Concept of product of linear maps in Serre's book Ex. 2.8

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Exercise 2.8 of Serre's book has been asked several times here ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415297/representation-problem-i-dont-understand-the-setting-of-the-question-from-se),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416390/representation-problem-from-serres-book),[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253853/choices-of-decompositions-of-a-representation-into-irreducible-components-serre?rq=1)).

The exercise description is:
Let $H$ be the vector space of linear maps $h:W_i\rightarrow V$ such that $\rho_s h = h \rho_s$ for all $s\in G$. Each $h \in H_i$ maps $W_i$ into $V_i$. Then, the exercise asked its questions.

My problem is I do not understand how we can write  $\rho_s h = h \rho_s$. If the dimension of $W_i$  and $V$ are $n_i$ and $N$, respectively, then my understanding is $h$ can be presented by $n_i \times N$ matrix, but $\rho_s$ is a mapping from $V$ to $V$ and can be represented by $N \times N$ matrix. So how are the $\rho_s$ and $h$ compatible, and how do $\rho_s h$ and $h \rho_s$ make sense?

The other problem is the statement "each $h \in H_i$ maps $W_i$ into $V_i$" is part of our assumptions or can be concluded from the fact that $h:W_i\rightarrow V$ such that $\rho_s h = h \rho_s$? Why?

I know if $h:W_i\rightarrow W_i$ and $\rho$ is an irreducible representation whose representation space is isomorphic to $W_i$ then Shure's lemma implies $h$ is an identity mapping times a constant. However, I do not understand rigorously how we can write $\rho_s h = h \rho_s$ and then restrict $\rho_s$ to irreducible representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking into account the fact that $V=W_1\oplus W_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus W_2 \oplus \dotsb W_2\oplus \dotsb \oplus W_k$ is an explicit decomposition into irreducible sub-representations. So, if $s\in G$, $\rho_s(W_i)\subset W_i$, for each $i$. In other words, you can see $\rho_s$ not only as a linear map from $V$ into $V$, but also as a linear map from $W_i$ into $W_i$ (again, for each $i$). So, in the equality $\rho_sh=h\rho_s$, you can see the $\rho_s$ on $\rho_sh$ as a map from $V$ into $V$ and the $\rho_s$ on $h\rho_s$ as a map from $W_i$ into $W_i$.

Comment: With your explanation, I understand if $x \in W_i$, then $\rho_s h x= h \rho_sx$ and what it means to restrict to $W_i$, but unless $h: V \rightarrow V$, I do not understand the $\rho_s h$. We can decompose $x \in V$ such that $x=x_1^1+\cdots x_1^{c_1}+\cdots+x_k^1+\cdots x_k^{c_k}$ and say $hx=0+\lambda_1 x_i^1+\cdots \lambda_{c_i}x_i^{c_i}+0$ provided that $h: V \rightarrow V$. When $h: W_i \rightarrow V$, how can $x \in V$? Does $h: W_i \rightarrow V$ mean $h(W_i)\subset W_i$ and $h(W_j)=0$ for $i \ne j$?

Comment: Since $h$ is a map from $W_i$ into $V$ and $\rho_s$ is a map from $V$ into $V$, $\rho_sh$ (that is, $\rho_s\circ h$) makes sense. And, no, it is not assumed here that $h(W_i)\subset W_i$ nor that $h(W_j)=\{0\}$ when $j\ne i$.